How can I create a multiline text-area input field in Microsoft Word 365?
I'm using Office 365. MS Word comes with a Plain Text Content Control command that creates a field that accepts text input from those who view the Word document.
Example:

This input field will expand to the size of the input and will wrap if the input is long enough, but it does not accept newline characters (pressing Return/Enter or pasting a newline does not work to create a line break).
I need to figure out how to create a text input field that allows line breaks to be inserted. This would be similar to the HTML <textarea> input. The solution needs to be natively supported, and anything that's already pre-written would take precedence over making a new macro.

Rich Text Content Control has the behavior I wanted out of the box. By default, it is found in the Controls group of the Developer tab.
For a more restrictive input field, you can use the Text Box (ActiveX Control). In the Controls group, find the Legacy Tools drop-down and look in the AcitveX Controls section. In properties, set EnterKeyBehavior to True and MultiLine to True.

How do I create a text input field that allows line breaks to be inserted?
You don't need VBA for this as you can just change the properties of the text input:

By default, text boxes can accommodate a single line of text. If you
want a text box to be able to accommodate multiple lines of text, you
can enable paragraph breaks or text wrapping for the text box after
you insert it onto your form template.

Right-click the text box for which you want to enable multiple lines of text, and then click Text Box Properties on the shortcut
menu.

Click the Display tab.

To enable multiple lines of text to be typed in the text box, select the Multi-line check box, and then optionally do one of the
following:

To prevent users from being able to insert paragraph breaks in the text box by pressing ENTER, clear the Paragraph breaks check box.

To prevent text from automatically wrapping to the next line when the user types more text than the width of the text box, clear
the Wrap text check box.



In the Scrolling list, click the text-scrolling option that you want.



Source: Enable a text box to accept multiple lines of text - Microsoft Support

This is outdated, but it helped me find the right answer.
